# How can I aggregate after special IDs in a coulmn in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have received from a **select** query this kind of table (just a simple example):

```
D         C         Letter
20153     200       x
20154     300       x
20161     250       x
20162     180       x
20153     500       y
20154     380       y
20161     550       y
20162     170       y
20153     230       z
20154     700       z
20161     210       z
20162     185       z
```

So, the column D repeats after four entries. C is always different and Letter changes after four entries.

I would now like sum up every D (all 20153, all 20154,...) and put this sum as a column next to Letter.

Something like this would be great:

```
D         C         Letter     Sum
20153     200       x          930
20154     300       x          1380
20161     250       x          1010
20162     180       x          535
20153     500       y          930
20154     380       y          1380
20161     550       y          1010
20162     170       y          535
20153     230       z          930
20154     700       z          1380
20161     210       z          1010
20162     185       z          535
```

I already tried ROLLUP and CUBE, but this didn't work as expected.
After that, I want to calculate the percentage of C according to Sum.

Comment: No id or timestamp column?

Comment: No, the D is the Date (YYYYQ) Q=Quartal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want analytic functions:

```
select d, c, letter, sum(c) over (partition by d) as d_sum
from t
order by letter;
```

Comment: Ok, that works just fine. I just saw that I made a mistake. Let's say my table from my question consists from x,y and z. But there are also a, b, and so on...So the total number of '20153' is '100.000', '20154' is '200.000', '20161' is '250.000' and '20162' is '150.000'. How can I add these values to "D" as a new column?

Comment: @victoria14 . . . I don't fully understand what you mean in the comment.  New questions should be asked as questions rather than as a comment.  If you just want to add the sum to another column, use `+`.